# Can't host localhost create Django application in Openshift

Tags: django, openshift

I have Django-1.6 connected to Mysql and running in my local-host. I push that [asowac](https://github.com/nuwan600/openshift-asowac) project to github to host in [open-shift](https://openshift.redhat.com). Then I created a application called [asowac-attsoc.rhcloud](http://asowac-attsoc.rhcloud.com/) in open-shift and connect it to the github [asowac](https://github.com/nuwan600/openshift-asowac) repository. But now it show me 404 error when go the URL. What is the reason for this and how can I fix this error?
This is the error[image]

Comment: show the url.py and settings to url.

Comment: Url.py-https://github.com/nuwan600/openshift-asowac/blob/master/attsoc/urls.py, manage.py- https://github.com/nuwan600/openshift-asowac/blob/master/manage.py and settings.py -https://github.com/nuwan600/openshift-asowac/blob/master/attsoc/settings.py

Comment: What does it show in your error logs?

Comment: this is the error logs plz look at this https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Screenshot%20from%202014-09-23%2010%3A22%3A53.png?_subject_uid=255434747&w=AABB39N_II6WhfmBzQpHIfRLT-jj5O9miLeB5dy4RnOhHQ,https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Screenshot%20from%202014-09-23%2010%3A27%3A51.png?_subject_uid=255434747&w=AADxgm7O8gr-gIJTMTIY7qSFlpQw-qwTYV3QBH3TQTiIlQ, https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Screenshot%20from%202014-09-23%2010%3A28%3A02.png?_subject_uid=255434747&w=AACylReRZ2irRwQ90Zaj8OJimIMAQmkXdm6mBSUM2ELW8Q